# Problem with permalinks

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, slug

I have changed the category base name and now it is "blog", it works ok.

But when I change structure by /blog/%category%/%postname%/. It shows 404.

If I remove blog in structure it works again, but I want to use blog word.

Where is the problem?

Thank you

[image: permalinks error]

Answer (score 0):

What happening is that WP is searching for a category rather your post. So the category rewrites come before post rewrites and that is making the WP confused.

For more info about the rewrites, I can point you to an excellent article [here](https://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/)

Comment: If WP search my category first, is not possible use this permalink?

Comment: Any function that it let me change the permalink?

Comment: Why you don't leave the Category base empty and leave the permalink structure as is. This way will have the `example.com/blog/category-name/post-name`

Comment: because then in my categories url don´t show the name blog before

Comment: Look at it this way. For this url: `http://example.com/blog/one/two`. Is `two` a post in category `one`? Or is `two` a subcategory of `one`? You can't tell by looking at it, and neither can WordPress. You need to provide some way to distinguish them.

Comment: You can't have this. The WP or even a custom code, how will can go and differentiate between `^/blog/(.*)` as a category and `^/blog/(.*)` as a post?

Comment: I understand you, but If I need the same structure in post that in categories... Is not possible? :(